# What did the peasants do in Japanese warfare?

Tags: medieval-japan

From what I understand, warfare in feudal Japan used to work like this - samurai sought out worthy opponents, they would duel, and the winner would move on to find another suitable foe.

But what about common foot soldiers, such as the *ashigaru*? What role did they play in warfare? Were they just used to hold off the enemy's commoners, and once a side's commoners were routed, their nobles would withdraw? Was it acceptable to send some "extra" commoners to take down a particularly skilled nobleman ahead of such an event, or did the nobility effectively have a separate battle going on?

Comment: These depictions are highly idealized, and many of the works in which they appear were written well **after** the feudal wars in Japan ended; warriors (and leaders) were usually more pragmatic than that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bushido

Comment: @SJuan76 - I'd imagine you'd come away with the same conceptions of Medieval European warfare, if you gathered all your info about it from [Chivarlic Romance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chivalric_romance) works.

Comment: @SJuan76 I did not know that. I will accept a description of how the battles *actually* worked as an answer. Even if it is just "everyone fought everyone, as so and so source states."